# ZF2 + doctrine2. Команды orm:validate-schema, orm:schema-tool:update и т.д. из контроллера?

Tags: doctrine2, zend-framework

Я пишу контроллер, который устанавливает систему, в том числе он будет создавать таблицы в бд с помощью doctrine2. Получается, что мне нужен аналог команд orm:info, orm:validate-schema, orm:schema-tool:update в php коде, а не в консоли. Можно ли это как-нибудь сделать?

Answer (score 1):

можете вызвать команду консоли из php - [exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php).

Я полагаю что это решит вашу проблему. Так же можете там поискать аналогичную, которая выводи инфо, чтобы проверить результат выполнения команды.